# GTK+: passing data with g_signal_connect not working

Tags: c++, gtk

I am trying to pass data allocated in the heap through g_signal_connect but it is showing some strange behavior.

I am passing the value this way:

```
int *test = new int(100);
g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT(deviceButton), "button_press_event", G_CALLBACK(showDeviceAndConnect), (gpointer) test);
```

And to print the value:

```
static void showDeviceAndConnect(GtkWidget * deviceButton, gpointer data)
{
    int *test = (int *) data;
    fprintf(stderr, "Test: %d\n", *test);
}
```

The value that gets printed is 4 all the time. I changed new int() to be 3, 5, etc.., it always prints 4.

I am extremely confused. Does anyone please know what is wrong?

EDIT:

Someone helped me figure it out. The function signature was actually wrong and missing one parameter. It is quite stupid but was hard to figure out.

Comment: Someone helped me figure it out. The function signature was actually wrong and missing one parameter. It is quite stupid but was hard to figure out.

Comment: You seem to be using C++. Consider using the [Gtkmm](http://www.gtkmm.org) C++ wrapper which adds (compile-time) type-safety to most places that lack it in C. Plus allows you to connect methods directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, your signature of the callback for [GtkWidget::button_press_event](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-button-press-event) is wrong. But if it's the click on a GtkButton that you want to detect, connect to the 
[GtkButton::clicked](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/stable/GtkButton.html#GtkButton-clicked) signal instead.